# Progress bar animation working only in IE10

Tags: css, microsoft-metro

I happened to post a question on linear animation that outlook.com presents and some of our friends here told me that its not possible. I was able to achieve that with CSS3 keyframes. However, it seems to work only in IE10 and not in Firefox and Chrome. I have put alternate tags for firefox and chrome from w3schools still I am not sure why its not working. Here is the link from jsfiddle which contains my code. I am also putting github link just in case. Please help me in this regard.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usaipavan/Zjwvf/)

[Github](https://raw.github.com/USaiPavan/WebAppPlayground/master/WebAppPlayground/AnimatedDots.html)

Part of my code is as follows. This code is repeated for each .(dot) with slight change in timings. There are 5 dots like this.

```
 .linearAnimate1
{
    animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-delay:0s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation-delay:0s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    animation-duration: 10s;
    -moz-animation-duration:10s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation-duration:10s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite; /*Safari and Chrome*/
    animation-name: makedotspin1;
    -moz-animation-name: makedotspin1;
    -webkit-animation-name: makedotspin1;

}

@keyframes makedotspin1 {
    from {
      animation-timing-function: ease;
      -moz-animation-timing-function:ease; /* Firefox */
      -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
      transform: translateX(0px);
      -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
      visibility:visible;
    }
    25% {
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in; /* Firefox */
      -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in; /* Safari and Chrome */
      transform: translateX(450px);
      -moz-transform: translateX(450px);
      -webkit-transform: translateX(450px);          
      animation-delay: 0.5s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;

    }
    50% {
      animation-timing-function: ease-inout;
      transform: translateX(900px);
      -moz-transform: translateX(900px);
      -webkit-transform: translateX(900px);
      visibility:hidden;
      animation-delay: 10s;
      -moz-animation-delay: 10s;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
    }
    to
    {
    }
}
```

[Animated buttons metro style progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236783/animated-buttons-metro-style-progress-bar) (to show it can't only be done using a gif

Comment: Seems to be working on FF 17 on Ubuntu 12.10. I don't know the correct animation, but I suspect the 5 dots appearing from left to right and then disappearing from left to right again is correct.

Comment: Yes the animation is correct. Left to Right 50% ease in and later rest 50% of space it will ease out. However, it is still not working on FF17 on Windows. Not sure :(. Chrome doesn't even show the dots

Comment: I updated your JSFiddle Code using a different approach:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zjwvf/1
Could you see if its working?

Comment: It doesn't work. The bad part is it stopped working in IE10 as well

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to have a prefix for @keyframes for the different layout engines, in example:

@-webkit-keyframes {}
@-moz-keyframes

etc, IE10 works because it supports the official spec

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tosh. I regret to inform that this approach did not work I have put @-webkit- and @-moz- and still does not show up the animation as it shows up in IE10

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found out the issue. Since I have used an unordered list I have used the following CSS

```
 ul li
    {
        display: inline;       
        font-size:4em; 
        visibility:hidden;   
    }
```

However, Mozilla and chrome are unable to do animation because the display is inline and all the list items are on top of each other. To fix the issue I had to do two things 1) I had to add -moz- and -webkit- prefixes for keyframes 2) Change the display to be inline-block as follows and it fixed the issue. Now the animation works on Mozilla, IE and Chrome

```
 ul li
    {
        display: inline-block;       
        font-size:4em; 
        visibility:hidden;   
    }
```